# How to set to initial state in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array that creates a mapping of items with checkboxes. each item has a checked state:

```
const [checked, setChcked] = React.useState(false)
```

So the user checks say 5 out of the 20 checkboxes and then press a button (the button is in the higher component, where there is a mapping that creates this items with checkboxes) and it works as intended. But, after the button is pressed and the modal is closing, after I open the modal again, these 5 checkboxes are still checked. I want them to restart to be unchecked just like when I refresh and the state vanishes. Now, I am aware of techniques such as not saving state per each item and just saving the state of the array of items in the higher component but I am confused as I have heard that hooks were created so that it is good practice to sometime save state in dumb components.

Is there a simpler function to just restart to initial value?

Edit: 
adding the code

```
           <div>
            {policyVersionItems.map(item=> (
              <PolicyVersionItem
                key={pv.version}
                policyVersionNumber={item.version}
                policyVersionId={item._id}
                handleCheck={handleCheck}
              >
                {' '}
              </PolicyVersionItem>
            ))}
          </div>
```

And the item

```
const PolicyVersionItem: React.FunctionComponent<PolicyVersionItemProps> = props => {
const { , policyVersionNumber, policyVersionId, handleCheck } = props
const [checked, setChcked] = React.useState(false)
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <Label dark={isEnabled}> Version {policyVersionNumber}</Label>
            <Checkbox
                checked={checked}
                onClick={() => {
                    if (isEnabled || checked) {
                        setChcked(!checked)
                        handleCheck(policyVersionId, !checked)
                    }
                }}
            />
    </Wrapper>
)
```

}

Some of it is not relevant. the handle check function is a function that returns data to the higher component from the lower component for example.

Comment: Please add the rest of the code

Comment: pass a prop like `submitted` to checkbox components, and `useEffect` to reset them if submitted is true

Comment: edited and added the code

Comment: um I think the reason is that when you close the modal you might just be hiding it by css in which case you might have to set the all the checkboxes to false on exiting the modal

Comment: definitely, you just need to make your popup disappear from DOM. then after it;s recreated all child components will be re-created as well. or you may use [reset by `key` prop](https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e) technique for the same outcomes(re-creation).

Comment: Please add the full code for the parent component (the one that creates the items). Which component opens the modal and what happens when it closes?